# How to register a Broadcast Receiver in a class that extends BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I have seen all the examples regarding registration of a `BroadcastReceiver` and all of them have registered a receiver without extending the `BroadcastReceiver` class. But I have the following code

```
package vertex2016.mvjce.edu.bluealert;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.UUID;

public class SearchBLDev extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private BluetoothAdapter BTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    private ArrayAdapter BTArrayAdapter;
    private ListView BTListView;
    private BluetoothDevice BTD;
    public UUID myUUID;

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

    public void discoveryStart()
    {
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(SearchBLDev, filter) //PROBLEM OCCURS HERE        
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {}
}
```

I can register a Receiver using the registerReceiver method. It shows error.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: how are you registering that is causing the error? And what is the error?

Comment: Did you try doing `registerReceiver(this, filter)`?

Comment: @SQLiteNoob it shows a "Can't resolve method" error

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler Yes, but the problem is, the `registerReceiver(this,filter)` turns red in color & shows some "Can't resolve method" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Context to call `registerReceiver(this, filter)`, so you should pass it as a parameter.

```
public void discoveryStart(Context context)
{
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    context.registerReceiver(this, filter) //PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
}
```

Then you can call it from your `Activity`:

```
SearchBLDev broadcastReceiver = new SearchBLDev();
broadcastReceiver.discoveryStart(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the receiver to your manifest?  Where do you initialize this broadcastReceiver?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, but I'm more inclined to implement it programmatically